# PHP preg_quote in replacement string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I use preg_replace and I want to include a url inside the replacement string. How do I quote that string? It appears preg_quote is only for the search pattern.

```
$replace = '\1'.addslashes($url).'\3'.addslashes($title).'\4';
```

Comment: What are you attempting to do?  The replace string is not passed through the regex engine and therefore does not need to be escaped.  Any back-references should be referenced by `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Comment: You could add more of an example to your question so it's clear what you do.

Comment: @hakre, obviously OP wants to know how to properly escape replacement strings in `preg_replace` so that the replacement is exactly what is originally in the string (no matter its content). What more would you want to know?

Comment: @Qtax: What is `$subject`? What is `$url`? What is `$title`?. Just the basics, it's not clear from the question and would be good to have to give examples according to the question. To properly escape both the matches from `$subject` as well as the variable values, I added an answer that deals with the deficiencies of any escape function that is applied prior replacement (namely the problem of double-escaping).

Answer (score 5):

1. Escapes are needed
2. `addslashes` is not sufficient
3. `preg_quote` escapes too much

See [this demo](http://ideone.com/Xna11).

As Mario commented you can use `addcslashes($str, "\\$")`.

Comment: Can you add code from "this demo" directly to your post, please? The link has rotted and no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no generic way to do this, but `addslashes` should be enough in most cases.

For maximum safety you can use the `${1}` syntax. E.g.

```
$replace = '${1}'.addslashes($url).'${3}'.addslashes($title).'${4}';
```

If you really want to be **totally bulletproof**, use a callback replacement function with [`preg_replace_callback()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php). The string returned from the callback function is used entirely as-is, so you don't have to worry about mixing replacement syntax with normal text.

Example with `preg_replace_callback()`:

```
class URLReplacer {
    public $pattern = '/my regex/';
    public $url;
    public $title;
    function __construct($url, $title) {
        $this->url = $url;
        $this->title = $title;
    }
    function _callback($matches) {
        return $matches[1].$url.$matches[3].$title.$matches[4];
    }
    function replace($subject) {
        return preg_replace_callback($this->pattern, array($this, '_callback'), $subject);
    }
}
$repl = new URLReplacer($url, $title);
$replaced = $repl->replace($subject);
```

Comment: preg_replace_callback() seems like a good solution. Any idea how to pass other variables, such as the url+title to the callback function?

Comment: Use a method instead of a function as your callback, and put the extra variables you need as properties of the object.  Then supply your callback to `preg_replace_callback()` like `array($callbackobj, 'callbackmethodname')`

Comment: @Tike: You could also use the lazy version with an `/e` expression as replacement string to pull them from the local scope.

Comment: @Tike: Something like `preg_replace("/(..)(..)/e", '"$1".$url."$2"', $src)` -- Okay, now that I look at it; it's actually awful. But would be a shortcut to the callback approach.

Answer (score 0):

You did not provide an example, so I compiled one on my own. The working solution I came up with is using a simple callback function:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/';
$title = 'Make it Complex \4';

$subject = 'Call \\4 " $me an url';
$pattern = '/(.*)an()( )(url)/';

$replace = function($m) use ($url, $title)
{
    return "$m[1]$url$m[3]$title$m[4]";
};

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $replace, $subject);
```

Result:

```
Call \4 " $me http://example.com/ Make it Complex \4url
```

The callback function is a so called [anonymous function <sup>*Docs*</sup>](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) which makes it easy to edit the code in place.

In case you need this more often you can put that into a function of your own, probably to make it more re-useable. You can even go to that far and create yourself your own pattern to replace subgroup matches and variables. For examle `{\1}` stands for the subpattern 1 match, `{$2}` for the second variable. Wrapping this into a function of it's own:

```
$patternf = function()
{
    $values = func_get_args();
    $mask = $values ? array_shift($values) : NULL;
    return function($matches) use ($mask, $values)
    {
        $parts = preg_split('/({[\\\\\\$][0-9]{1,3}})/', $mask, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        foreach($parts as &$part)
            if (preg_match('/^{([\\\\\\$])([0-9]{1,3})}$/', $part, $p))             
                $part = $p[1] == '\\' ? $matches[(int)$p[2]] : $values[$p[2]-1];
        return implode('', $parts);
    };
};
```

Would allow you to make the replacement more handy:

```
$replace = $patternf('{\1}{$1}{\3}{$2}{\4}', $url, $title);

$result = preg_replace_callback($pattern, $replace, $subject);
```

[Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/SeRVHw). Wrapping this into a function of it's own:

```
function preg_replace_subst($pattern, $replace, $subject)
{
    $values = func_get_args();
    $pattern = array_shift($values);
    $mask = array_shift($values);
    $subject = array_shift($values);
    $callback = function($matches) use ($mask, $values)
    {
        $parts = preg_split('/({[\\\\\\$][0-9]{1,3}})/', $mask, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE | PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
        foreach($parts as &$part)
            if (preg_match('/^{([\\\\\\$])([0-9]{1,3})}$/', $part, $p))             
                $part = $p[1] == '\\' ? $matches[(int)$p[2]] : $values[$p[2]-1];
        return implode('', $parts);
    };
    return preg_replace_callback($pattern, $callback, $subject);
}
```

Would give it an easy interface:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/';
$title = 'Make it Complex \4';

$subject = 'Call \\4 " $me an url';
$pattern = '/(.*)an()( )(url)/';

$replace = '{\1}{$1}{\3}{$2}{\4}';

$result = preg_replace_subst($pattern, $replace, $subject, $url, $title);
```

But with many substitution variables it should be possible to pass them as an array probably otherwise it gets a bit lengthy.

#### Using the `e` modifier with `preg_replace` (and why it does not work)

When using the `e` modifier, the matches get replaced in the replace string and it then get's evaluated. As other variables do not get escaped, the matches do interfere with PHP variable substitution, which is dangerous:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/';
$title = 'Make it Complex \4';

$subject = 'Call me an url.';

$pattern = '/(.*)an()( )(url)/e';
$replace = '"$1{$url}$3{$title}$4"';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $subject);
```

Outputs:

```
Call me http://example.com/ Make it Complex \4url.
```

As written, the first `e`-modifier example is broken because `$` won't get escape in `$subject`, so PHP would have looked for unset variables. That's dangerous, too. I came up with a variant, it solves that issue but it can't handle double-quotes in the subject:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/';
$title = 'Make it Complex \4';

$subject = 'Call \\4 " $me an url';

$pattern = '/(.*)an()( )(url)/e';
$replace = "'\$1'.\$url.'\$3'.\$title.'$4'";
```

Output:

```
Call \4 \" $me http://example.com/ Make it Complex \4url
        ^ problem, not in input.
```

So not really fool-proof, that's why it needs the callback function because it gets the matching sub-patterns unquoted.

Comment: This is a good solution too. I would use this for simple or one-off code, and `preg_replace_callback` with method callback for more complex replacements or code that needs to be maintained for a while.

Comment: Actually I just saw my code is broken if `$subject` contains `$`. I'm fiddling a bit, what I wrote about what get's escape by regex does not include `$`.

Comment: Oh, I didn't catch that. How unfortunate :(

Comment: @FrancisAvila: Yes, somehow ;) And I could not work around it with the `e` modifier finally, so I added a callback example as well.

Comment: I've never seen that `function () use () {}` syntax before. Is this a php 5.3 feature? Can you provide a link to php documentation that explains that? I can't find one.

Comment: That's PHP 5.3, yes. It's documented here: [Anonymous Functions (PHP)](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

Comment: Why all this when a simple 20 char solution (`addcslashes`) works perfectly? What am I missing?

Comment: @Qtax: To what are you adding the slashes? To `$subject`? To `$url`/`$title`? If you add them to `$subject` you add too much. If you add them to `$url` or `$title`, you add too much, too. E.g. if `title` contains a `$` character for example. If you add it to `$subject` and it contains a `$` or "\" character the same problem appears. `e` modifier doesn't work either, I tested with `addcslashes` as it sounded like an easy solution but it ain't properly working.

Comment: It is tried and working, see for your self. The replacement string `\\ \$` (these are not escapes, just characters) produces the replacement `\ $` in the result string.

Comment: @Qtax: Provide working example code with `$subject` and substitution of `$url` and `$title` for a replacement as given in the question (`$replace`) so it can be easily edited and demonstrated for which values it does not work. It works for some cases and `addcslashes` is a good tool to control where to add slashes, but it still has side-effects for various input values.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5539/discussion-between-qtax-and-hakre)

Comment: @hakre I think you overthought this. `$url = 'http://example.com/';
$title = 'Make it Complex \4';

$subject = 'Call \\4 " $me an url';
$pattern = '/(.*)an()( )(url)/';

$result = preg_replace($pattern, '\1'.addcslashes($url, '\\$').'\3'.addcslashes($title, '\\$').'\4', $subject);` gives the same result.

Answer (score 0):

To make it obvious one is escaping any potential back-references in the `$replacement` parameter of `preg_replace()`, use a function:

```php
function preg_quote_replacement($input) {
    return addcslashes($input, '\\$');
}
```

In OP's case:

```php
$subject = preg_replace(
    $pattern,
    '\1'.preg_quote_replacement($url).'\3'.preg_quote_replacement($title).'\4',
     $subject
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Prepared Patterns](https://t-regx.com/docs/handling-user-input). It works like Prepared Statements in SQL:

```
Pattern::inject("\1@url\2@url\3", ['url' => $input]);
```